Counting Grouped Data in Moodle
I read some data from the database. To do this, I group the values ​​according to the "date" and the "ustd".
Can I have it count beforehand how many "ustd" it has summarized?
I read the data as follows:
$lbtbs = $DB->get_records('lbtb_schulzentrum', null, 'date,ustd', 'id,date,ustd,eintrag,sus,bgcolor');

Then I run it through a foreach loop:
foreach ($lbtbs as $lbtb) {
    $data[$lbtb->date][$lbtb->ustd] = array("date" => $lbtb->date, "id" => $lbtb->id, "start" => $lbtb->ustd, "description" => $lbtb->eintrag, "sus" => $lbtb->sus, "color" => $lbtb->bgcolor);
}

Briefly describe what I want:
I have the following records:



id
date
ustd




1
2024-08-22
1


2
2024-08-22
1


3
2024-08-22
2


4
2024-08-22
2


5
2024-08-22
3



The first two records have the same date and the same ustd number. This means that I want to group the two records. This works so far. However, I would also like to pass on the "2" (count the records: 2 records = output 2, 3 records = output 3).
My output that I want to have:



id
date
ustd
count




1
2024-08-22
1
2


3
2024-08-22
2
2


5
2024-08-22
3
1



Edit:
I tried using COUNT. Unfortunately, the data that is counted is no longer output.
$lbtbs = $DB->get_records_sql('SELECT id,date,ustd,bgcolor,sus, COUNT(sus) FROM {lbtb_schulzentrum}');

$data = array();

foreach ($lbtbs as $lbtb) {
    $data[$lbtb->date][$lbtb->ustd] = array("date" => $lbtb->date, "id" => $lbtb->id, "start" => $lbtb->ustd, "color" => $lbtb->bgcolor);
}

Solution:
The GROUP BY was missing and COUNT(*) AS count to access the value.
$lbtbs = $DB->get_records_sql('SELECT id,date,ustd,bgcolor,sus, COUNT(*) AS count FROM {lbtb_schulzentrum} GROUP BY date,ustd');


What is the error message that you get?

I have modified the query a little. The error message was due to a ",". However, when I count the values, this exact data is no longer output. I have listed my SQL query above under "Edit:".

I think it's because of the foreach loop. I assume I can't output multiple entries being counted at once?

I need to know the error message that you get in order to help.

I no longer have an error message. The problem I have now is that it only outputs one data set based on COUNT(). But I need several.

Always let the database do the work, it is faster and more efficient than using PHP code
SQL Aggregate
COUNT() is an aggregate function, like SUM(), MIN(), MAX()
When using aggregate functions, you need to use a GROUP BY column names
In your case this will be something like
GROUP BY date, ustd

You will need to use a group by on every column in your SELECT
It's also useful to use an alias for the count column eg:
COUNT() AS mycount

Unique column
In Moodle, the first column in the $DB->get_records_sql() function needs to be a unique value
The id column in the lbtb_schulzentrum table is a unique value, but a bit pointless for a GROUP BY because it will return every row
So use concat to join the date and ustd columns to make a unique id. In addition, Moodle can use several different databases, so use the compatibility function $DB->sql_concat()
$DB->sql_concat('date', 'ustd')

See https://moodledev.io/docs/4.4/apis/core/dml#sql_concat
Final code
So your final sql should look like
$sql = "SELECT " . $DB->sql_concat('date', 'ustd') . " AS uniqueid, date, ustd, COUNT() AS mycount
        FROM {lbtb_schulzentrum}
        GROUP BY date, ustd";

$lbtbs = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);

Column names
And just a tip, date is a reserved column name
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/XMLDB_reserved_words
So if your code is used on different databases, it might break
When creating tables, I would recommend using the XMLDB Editor
Go to Site Admin > Development > XMLDB Editor

Thank you for the detailed explanation!
It works great and I can even understand the explanations very well!

You just need to group by, like
SELECT min(id) as id, min(date) as date,ustd COUNT(sus) FROM {lbtb_schulzentrum} GROUP BY ustd

